# Get data that have multiple row and different status

Tags: mysql

I have **transaction_record** table that contains **transaction_code**, **item_code**, **item_status**. **transaction_code** can have multiple **item_code**. My table looks like this.

```
transaction_code | item_code | item_status
T0001              I001        Delivered
T0002              I001        Delivered
T0002              I002        Failed
T0003              I003        Failed
T0003              I004        Failed
T0004              I003        Delivered
T0004              I005        Delivered
T0005              I004        Failed
```

My query now is something like this

```
SELECT transaction_code, item_code, item_status
FROM transaction_record
WHERE transaction_code IN
(SELECT transaction_code FROM transaction_record 
GROUP BY transaction_code HAVING COUNT(item_code) > 1)
GROUP BY transaction_code, item_code;
```

I need to find a partially successful transaction, **its a transaction that has both delivered item(s) and failed item(s)**. With my query, I still got T0002, T0003, and T0004 because they have more than 1 **item_code**. How can I get only T0002?

```
transaction_code | item_code | item_status
T0002              I001        Delivered
T0002              I002        Failed
```

Comment: how about adding `WHERE item_status in ('Delivered')`?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ then it will only return 'Delivered' transaction, I need a partially delivered transaction

Comment: Please mention in your question for your this query, what will be your desire output.

Comment: @AlimonKarim okay I already edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only possible `item_status` values are `Delivered` and `Failed`, you can get the transaction code for a transaction with both delivered and failed items by counting the number of distinct `item_status` values for each transaction; it will be 2 for those transactions:

```
SELECT transaction_code
FROM transaction_record tr
GROUP BY transaction_code
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_status) = 2
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
T0002
```

If you also want the rest of the information related to that transaction, use the above query as a subquery to match `transaction_code` values:

```
SELECT *
FROM transaction_record
WHERE transaction_code IN (
  SELECT transaction_code
  FROM transaction_record tr
  GROUP BY transaction_code
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_status) = 2)
```

Output

```
transaction_code    item_code   item_status
T0002               I001        Delivered
T0002               I002        Failed
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3zJhbxmSYAQRBFiNcUFaiA/0)

If there can be `item_status` values other than `Delivered` and `Failed`, you just need to add a `WHERE` clause to the subquery:

```
WHERE item_status IN ('Failed', 'Delivered')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3zJhbxmSYAQRBFiNcUFaiA/2)

Answer (score 1):

Your' almost near to the correct query.

```
select transaction_code from transaction_record
where transaction_code not in 
  (select transaction_code  
    from transaction_record
    group by item_status, transaction_code
    having count(1) > 1)
group by transaction_code
having count(1) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT transaction_code
FROM transaction_record
GROUP BY transaction_code
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_status) > 1
```